# Word boundary does not work inside brackets in regex

Tags: php, regex, cpu-word, brackets, boundary

I have noticed that the word boundary `\bword\b` does not work inside brackets when doing a `preg_replace()` in PHP.

Specifically, I'm trying to exclude the full word `&gt;` (which stands for `>` in HTML), but since the word boundary does not trigger inside brackets as in `[^\b&gt;\b]`, any of those characters by itself, like `g` or `&`, will be detected as a non-match. If you try to do a match outside the brackets, `\b` works as expected in PHP even though the word starts with a `&` a non-character.

Any thoughts/ideas to get around this situation?

Comment: That is because, inside the brackets (which is called a character class, by the way), `&gt;` is not a single entity any more. It is a list of characters — `&`, `g`, `t`, and `;`. `[^\b&gt;\b]` will match anything that is not one of the characters above, or a word boundary. (`\b` being repeated twice is redundant, and has no effect on the end result whatsoever).

Comment: what´s the solution then? I need to not-match the whole word, not the individual characters

Comment: Your use of *two* `\b`s inside the square brackets suggests you don't know what square brackets are for. I'd suggest a regex tutorial.

Comment: I have to use [] in this case because I'm doing a "all characters but these" condition which requires me to start with [^

Comment: @ᴹᴬᴺᴰᴿᴬᴷᴱ: How exactly is that question a duplicate?

Comment: @thedeadtree.: Just a formatting tip. For inline code formatting, you can wrap the piece of code in backticks: `foo bar &gt; baz bak`, and it will be displayed as it is. You can view the current markdown for the question by clicking [*Edit*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24257055/edit).

Comment: @thedeadtree. A negated character class means ~ "one character that is not one of the specified", thus `[^\b&gt;\b]` is the same as `[^;&\bgt]` (although I'm not sure `\b` will work inside a class), i.e. not a `;` *or* an `&`, and so on, since the order of the characters doesn't matter. If you want to negate a *sequence* of characters you'll should use [negative look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 1):

**To exclude in PHP, (*SKIP)(*F) is your friend**

In PHP, excluding anything is frighteningly simple thanks to the powerful `(*SKIP)(*F)` syntax (also available in Perl).

To exclude `&gt;` and watch something else, you can just do this:

```
&gt;(*SKIP)(*F)|something_else
```

The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `&gt;`then deliberately fails, after which the engine skips to the next position in the string. The right side matches `something_else`, and we know that it is not `&gt;` because it was not matched by the expression on the left. Just make sure that `something_else` is not something generic such as `.*` as that could roll over all the following `&gt;` instances. For instance, here, `\w+` would be a perfectly fine pattern for `something_else`, as it does not clash with `&gt;`

**Further reading about this and other techniques to exclude patterns in regex**

[How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)

Answer (score 0):

One solution to my own question is: instead of doing a `[^word]` condition, check if the word/sentence I want is *not* immediately followed by the word I don't want. As in:

```
&gt;(?!&gt;)
```

For my particular case, it worked.