# Why don't boundaries work in regex brackets?

Tags: c#, regex

To begin, I would like to note that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257055/word-boundary-does-not-work-inside-brackets-in-regex) exists with answers and workarounds specific to PHP. I am seeing this issue in C# and I would like to understand the logic behind this apparent "gotcha".

The word boundary character `\b` doesn't seem to work properly when placed inside a `Regex` set (aka "box brackets": `[]`). Is this a syntactic issue, are word boundaries intentionally excluded from set matching, or is there some other explanation I'm missing?

Here is a program to demonstrate the issue:

```
namespace TestProgram
{
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = "[abc]";
            var BaselineRegex = new Regex(@"(?:\b)(abc)");
            Debug.Assert(BaselineRegex.IsMatch(text)); // Assertion Passes
            var BracketRegex = new Regex(@"(?:[\b])(abc)");
            Debug.Assert(BracketRegex.IsMatch(text)); // Assertion Fails!
        }
    }
}
```

Here are web versions to demonstrate as well:

- Word boundary performing as expected without brackets: ([link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cb%29%28abc%29&i=%5babc%5d))
- Word boundary failing to match when placed inside brackets: ([link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5b%5cb%5d%29%28abc%29&i=%5babc%5d))

Comment: `[\b]` is a backspace char matching pattern, that is all. All zero-width assertions lose their meanings of zero-width assertions inside character classes.

Comment: Because there is no concrete, consumable assertion you can put in a character class, because, well, they're not characters.

Comment: Note how `^` and `$` do not function as beginning/end of string anchors within square brackets either. Character classes must at least be quantifiable.

Comment: A better question may be what is your true goal to have an anchor in a character set? I would surmise it is more how you setup your pattern that is the issue, and changing how you search might be more fruitful.

Answer (score -1):

To quote [Wiktor Stribiżew's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56265874/why-dont-boundaries-work-in-regex-brackets#comment99148031_56265874):

> `[\b]` is a backspace char matching pattern, that is all.

So while `\b` is a zero-width word boundary outside of a character class, it refers to the backspace character (`0x8` in ASCII) when used within a character class. Further details are provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438100/whats-the-use-of-the-b-backspace-regex).

Wiktor: If you would like to post your own answer I would be happy to accept it over this one.